# Incorrect appearance of the subfigures

Tags: subfloats, figure-placement

I am using below code to include 3 different images in the same figure. However, the caption for each subfigure is with format "Figure 7.2: Gráfico del estado OFF" instead of "a)Gráfico del estado OFF". how can I modify it? Thank you!!

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/images/Paciente_1_OFF.png}
     \caption{Paciente 1. Gráficos del estado OFF.}
     \label{fig:paciente_1_off}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/images/Paciente_1_ON.png}
     \caption{Paciente 1. Gráficos del estado OFF.}
     \label{fig:paciente_1_con}
 \end{subfigure}
 \newline
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.0\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Latex/images/Paciente_1_change.png}
     \caption{Paciente 1. Gráficos del estado cambio.}
     \label{fig:paciente_1_cambio}
 \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Corr. del EEG del paciente 1 en estado: a) OFF, b) cambio o intermedio y c) ON.}
    \label{fig_paciente_1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please complete your TeX code to be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. When I make your code snippet minimally compilable, I'm afraid I am unable to replicate the issue you say you've encountered. Specifically, the three subfigure numbers are of the form (a), (b), and (c).

Comment: Are you using the subcaption package, or the old subfigure package?